# Rotate UI Controls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, rotation

I have a project for my C# module where I want to make a booking system for the AULA(see picture below). I want the user to be able to click on a seat that has to be booked. I can do this with normal pictureboxes or datagridviews, but this would not be curved like the seats on the side.

Is it possible for me to rotate components in any degrees I choose or is there a better way for me to do this?
[image: Seating Plan]

Comment: "is there a better way for me to do this? " - write your own control?

Comment: What UI framework do you use? It's tough in Forms but easy in WPF.

Comment: @MitchWheat I am still in first year and don't know how to do this,  is it possible for you to please explain to me how to do this?

Comment: @nvoigt We have to use Windows forms Application

Comment: I would be more inclined to attempt something based on the concept of a background image, mouseovers, hotspots, and clicks.  You could simulate all of the necessary feedback in the Paint event(s).  Any explanation beyond that concept is far beyond the scope of any Q&A site.  You've a challenge ahead of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this [ImageMap control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2820/C-Windows-Forms-ImageMap-Control) in the past. You just need to provide the background image and a collection of polygons representing clickable areas. Those are internally added to a `GraphicsPath` searchable by the use of markers. The `GraphicsPath.IsVisible` method is used to detect whether the click point is interior to a certain area.